# Bean Not Getting Created When Using @Import

Tags: java, spring

I have a class (say Class A) that `@Autowire` a properties class (Class B). B's fields are read from `application.yml` and then a bean is created using `@Component`. This bean can then be used in class A using `@Autowire`.

When I run the application in the same module, all the beans are created fine and the application runs. But when I do a `@Import(A.class)` from a `@Configuration` class of another module (it's a multi-module project), the `bean` created for Class B contains all `null` values. This means that it is not reading the `application.yml` in it's module.

What can be the reason behind such behaviour?

Comment: `@Import` is supposed for(and from) `@Configuration` objects. (from my knowledge..it's an equivalent for `<bean:import/>`...in xml configurations) ... so try rather to `@Import` the configuration/context which is aware of "the bean".

Comment: ...so, the *value* of `@Import` should also be a `@Configuration` ..not a `@Bean`..or `@Component`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s03.html

Comment: Oh it solved it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the problem because you haven't shared code snippets or project structure etc. But have you tried scanning your packages with

```
@CoomponentScan(basepackages = {"package1","package2"})
```

above your application class. This way, spring will know where to look for all the classes.

Hope this helps. Please add code snippets, project structure etc. so that we can understand the problem and help.

If that's not the case, refer this, it might be the problem.

[Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)